# 'NCD.L1.sample--near-analytics' couldn't build project

Tags: nearprotocol

The repo: https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--near-analytics

The Demo VDO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-pn6I0VIYE

I've been trying to test the project on my own following the Demo VDO using the available code in the repo. However, the project couldn't be built with `yarn build`

Here is the error
[image: The Error]

I've also tried to get it to work using `yarn dev` and `yarn start` as available in the `package.json`, but none of that is working at the moment.

Pls let me know how I could get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried removing the node_modules folder and then doing a fresh yarn install? try running this `rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && yarn build`

Comment: Yes, I already did and got the exact same result as in the image attached.

Comment: I just tried to clone the project, run it with `yarn` then `yarn build`, and there were no errors.
You could try to use npm instead. `npm install` then run `npm run build:contract && npm run build:web` afterwards. I'm not sure it will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried to use the same node version (v16.13.1) and yarn version (v1.22.15) as your set-up (according to the images), but I'm still able to build the project. I would suggest you to clone the project in a different folder and try anew. I'm not sure why it's not working in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run `yarn` first to install dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this time I already did `yarn` and got the independence installed successfully as shown in the attached image.